Create s3 bucket policy
My goal to create an s3 bucket for static website hosting and add IAM policies for that s3 bucket.The bucket was OK, however the bucket policy is failing. I have three statement in the bucket policy and I can't guess which one is failing and why. I also need these policies because public access will denied.
Error: putting S3 Bucket (serengatti01bhg) Policy: operation error S3: PutBucketPolicy, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: 5TA4MQJ2Y0FNJ5FA, HostID: E+qj6u+HWZthQlkvOuQQRqE+pfdFOfPoceulLyDxy/70UCW7dVQU+X2GSdNs1a65LuLq9yWErOU=, api error AccessDenied: Access Denied
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "test01" {
  bucket = "serengatti01bhg"

  tags = {
    Name = "serengatti01bhg"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "test01_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.test01.id

  policy = jsonencode(
    {
      Version = "2012-10-17"
      Statement = [
        {
          Sid       = "pc_access"
          Effect    = "Allow"
          Action    = "s3:*"
          Principal = "*"
          Resource = [
            aws_s3_bucket.test01.arn,
            "${aws_s3_bucket.test01.arn}/*"
          ]
          Condition = {
            "IpAddress" = {
              "aws:SourceIp" = "my public ip"
            }
          }
        },

        {
          Sid    = "admins_access"
          Effect = "Allow"
          Action = "s3:*"
          Principal = {
            AWS = "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:user/ak"
          }
          Resource = [
            aws_s3_bucket.test01.arn,
            "${aws_s3_bucket.test01.arn}/*"
          ]
        },

        {
          Sid       = "ssl_policy"
          Effect    = "Deny"
          Principal = "*"
          Action    = "s3:*"
          Resource = [
            aws_s3_bucket.test01.arn,
          ]
          Condition = {
            Bool = {
              "aws:SecureTransport" = "false"
            }
          }
        },

        {
          Sid       = "PublicReadGetObject"
          Effect    = "Allow"
          Principal = "*"
          Action    = "s3:GetObject"
          Resource = [
            "${aws_s3_bucket.test01.arn}/*",
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  )
}


Two resources an s3 bucket and s3 bucket policy
Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy

Does the bucket have S3 Block Public Access set to ON? You will need to turn it OFF for the two options that mention Bucket Policies.

Side-note: When granting access to Groups of users (eg Admins), it is preferable to add the permissions to the IAM User or IAM Group directly, rather than doing it via a Bucket Policy. Normally, a Bucket Policy is only used for granting Public access or for granting cross-account permissions.

Side-note: I would not recommend granting s3:* to an IP address because it means anyone at that IP address has fully S3 access on your account. In an office, many people share the same IP address. At home, you might be assigned a different IP address by your ISP. It is better to grant permission on the IAM User themselves. That way, they use authenticated access when calling AWS.

I added the policy to the "Administrators" and I still can't add a policy to an s3 bucket. They are Administrators they suppose to have everything, yet even with this addition, I can't add policies to an s3 bucket.

It sounds like your Amazon S3 bucket has S3 Block Public Access activated. This will prevent you from adding a bucket policy, even as an Administrator:

To deactivate Block Public Access, click Edit and turn off the options that mention "Bucket Policies":

You will then be able to add a Bucket Policy to the bucket.

This policy is intended to block all operations on S3 resources if traffic is not sent over a secure HTTPS connection : Effect    = "Deny"
